# CWE ID 80 in Python Veracode Scan

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, veracode

I have a small Flask API that has been recently run through Vericode. Each one of my return statements has been flagged with "Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) (CWE ID 80)". I've read into this error, and it's related to escaping characters inside of the JSON response body.

I've tried using `jsonify`:

```
return jsonify(some_dict), 200
```

and `Response`:

```
return Response(some_dict, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

But both styles have been flagged. Has anyone seen this before? Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Veracode allows you to "mitigate" a group of flagged code; that was my "solution".